# Angular two way binding [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

Angular Two way binding

is in any case we can have

[(ngModel)] --> [(propertyName)]
is this possible
this has been asked to me in interview???

Comment: Yes it does work in a way, you would have to use `@Input` and `@Output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use two-way binding in many cases. There are a lot of examples in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-).

In cases where you have a component with an `@Input` and an `@Output` you can use it.

If this is your component:

**src/app/sizer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sizer',
  templateUrl: './sizer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sizer.component.css']
})
export class SizerComponent {


  @Input()  size: number | string;
  @Output() sizeChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  dec() { this.resize(-1); }
  inc() { this.resize(+1); }

  resize(delta: number) {
    this.size = Math.min(40, Math.max(8, +this.size + delta));
    this.sizeChange.emit(this.size);
  }

}
```

**src/app/sizer.component.html**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="dec()" title="smaller">-</button>
  <button (click)="inc()" title="bigger">+</button>
  <label [style.font-size.px]="size">FontSize: {{size}}px</label>
</div>
```

You can use it as follows:

```
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
<div [style.font-size.px]="fontSizePx">Resizable Text</div>
```

The secret here lies between suppose you wanted to have two way binding on size. So there should be one input with name size and one output with name sizeChange. This naming convention ensures to automatically bind it.

Comment: Output property name should be   @Output() sizeChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

size right???

Comment: if input name is size. Yes its mandatory to have name sizeChange for two way binding.